# SSHFS symbolic link does not show up

Tags: centos, terminal, mount, osx, sshfs

So this issue is actually occurring between OSX and CentOS.  I created an ssh mount using osxfuse:

```
sshfs [ssh config name]:/remote/location/dir.ec.tory ~/client/location/dir.ec.tory -o follow_symlinks
```

This had worked, but I imagine there was a timeout of some nature (or the server stopped responding) and the linkage broke.  When attempting to unmount (via `umount`) there were issues:

```
umount: ~/client/location/dir.ec.tory: not currently mounted
```

That's not uncommon; however `ls -la` no longer shows the directory.  Even if the there is no connection, the directories would remain after and be mounted on the local file system.  I have other directories that point to different paths on the server — these all worked and nothing has changed.

When trying to remount this is the error displayed:

```
sshfs [ssh config name]:/remote/location/dir.ec.tory ~/client/location/dir.ec.tory -o follow_symlinks
mount_osxfuse: /Users/<name>/SSH/dir.ec.tory: Input/output error
```

It's odd that `ls` does not show the directory.  Even odder is that tab-completion still worked for the directory.  Even trying to remove the directory `sudo rm ~/client/location/dir.ec.tory` it receives the same Input/output error.  If I try to remake the directory (`mkdir ~/client/location/dir.ec.tory`) it says  `File exists`

Does anyone know why or how I could display the directory again and recover from this error?  I've killed all the processes I could find related to ssh asside from the daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out not all processes were terminated.  There seemed to be a rogue process not assigned to my account.  Revealed by:

```
ps -ax | grep ssh
```

Killing the id that belonged to that process must have released something as the directory once again appeared and was re-accessible.  I'm not familiar with the terminal/fs enough to know why `ls` would not discover that directory, but would appreciate any insights some more experienced could divulge.